# Creating unit test from context menu in Visual Studio not working. Why?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

Using VS2015. No special plugins. Both my class and method are specified public.

I'm in a class. Right click. Click "Create Unit tests".

Error: "Create Unit Tests is supported only within a public class or public method"

Then the option disappears from the menu in that solution until I restart VS.

No one else I know has this problem in their IDEs of the same version. Any troubleshooting ideas? Or is there a setting that is causing this?

I did the obligatory quick internet search and nothing seemed to solve the problem. Your top solutions for a search for the text in the error will be the same as mine.

What do?

Comment: Is your class or method public? If not, then the error message is telling you what the problem is

Comment: Yes, they're both public.